# Some sort of error

Tags: android

Something is wrong with my java file, but I don't know what it is. Can someone please tell me. 
BTW, I'm new to this

Thank You

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Nevermind I got it

Comment: Close the question then.

Answer (score 3):

Closing braces are missing as far as i can see.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give 2 closing braces after super statement

Answer (score 0):

> you are missing closing } braces.

put the 2 closing `}` braces after your `onCreate()` callback .

Example:-

```
package com.example;

import..

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```